# iOS - how to set picker data when I use uiview to uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, picker

hello guys I'm trying to make some util that I need like Pokedex kk

but I have some problem. I make the picker in separate view and I call that view in tabview and use it.

but I don't know how to set the data. If I make picker in uiviewcontroller I can set data in **didload?** method but in uiview there are no **didload** method that I can set.

this is my code

> SelectPoke.swift

```
class SelectPoke: UIView , UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

var data =  ["1","2","3"]
var picker = UIPickerView()

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return data.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField.text = data[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return data[row]
}

func h(){
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    h()
}

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "SelectPoke", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

}

> Tab1ViewController.swift

```
class Tab1ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let sideView = SelectPoke.instanceFromNib()
    sideView.frame = self.view.frame

    self.view.addSubview(sideView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

plz help me. my Pokemon is waiting..

Comment: Is it really intended that you use `SelectPoke` as a UIView subclass?
Typically you would implement  the delegate and datasource in the `Tab1ViewController`.

Comment: check if initWithCoder method call when you loading view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would not subclass `UIPickerView`, but create a view in a Storyboard (or XIB-file) and
connect the delegate and data source with the `Tab1ViewController`.

Nevertheless, in this code we'll just create a new `UIPickerView` in `viewDidLoad`, to keep the code similar to the original question

*Remark*: Currently I have no Xcode running, so there might be small syntactial errors in this code example

```
 class Tab1ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var data =  ["1","2","3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sideView = UIPickerView()
        sideView.frame = self.view.frame

        self.view.addSubview(sideView)
        sideView.delegate = self
        sideView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textField.text = data[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[row]
    }
}
```